# Rename different files to one file name, one at a time

Tags: file, batch-file, dos, batch-rename

i have files named..

```
82011.nsf
63113.nsf
55555.nsf
```

i must rename each file to 
single.nsf (for example ren 82011.nsf to single.nsf)

then use a program to act on that file (single.nsf)

then rename the next file (63113.nsf to single.nsf)
then use a program to act on that file (single.nsf)
etc

I want a batch file to do the nename, pause (so i can run the other program), then do the next rename until all nsf files are done.

how?

Comment: Does the other program have a flag that you can use to specify a filename, so that you don't have to rename each one as `single.nsf`? Or if not, do you have the code to that program so that you can add that facility?

Answer (score 1):

```
for %i in (*.nsf) do ( 
  rename %i single.nsf 
  do_the_job 
  pause 
)
```

Comment: thnak you for your help this is the final solution for me.    for /f %%v IN ('dir /b *.era') do copy %%v nownsf.nsf & pause

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
for /f %%fname IN (‘dir /b *.nsf’) do call myprog %%a
```

*[[src](http://jamesewelch.com/2008/05/01/how-to-write-a-dos-batch-file-to-loop-through-files/)]*

Comment: You cannot use `%%fname` there. Also you shouldn't use `for /f` over the output of `dir` unless it's absolutely necessary. While it may have worked for this case you get yourself in minor pain with file names that contain spaces or Unicode characters that don't have a representation in the OEM codepage (unless you're using a TrueType font for the console; but that isn't the default, so always expect things to break).