# Renaming of Zip files in sequence

Tags: vba, batch-file, cmd

I would like to rename a single zip file every 30 mins via Sched task.

File list:

BULK_CALL1.ZIP BULK_CALL2.ZIP BULK_CALL3.ZIP ect..

Into:

BULK_CALL.ZIP BULK_CALL2.ZIP BULK_CALL3.ZIP ect..

The BULK_CALL.ZIP will be deleted by a program. Therefore in 30 mins time I would like BULK_CALL2.ZIP to be renamed to BULK_CALL.ZIP and so on until all the files have been processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST bulk_call.zip FOR %%i IN (bulk_call*.zip) DO REN %%i bulk_call.zip&GOTO :eof
```

MAY do what you want - depending on a better explanation of your requirements.

Are you worried about the sequence in which the file is processed - whether it's called `bulk_call?.zip` or `test?.txt`

Is the required sequence date-order?

if so, try

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST bulk_call.zip FOR /f %%i IN ( 
  ' dir /b /a-d /od bulk_call*.zip ' ) DO REN %%i bulk_call.zip&GOTO :eof
```

Comment: Your first simple answer did the job. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: The solution will start renaming files in the wrong order after the first iteration if there are files with a number >=10.

Comment: @ansgar - sure, that's why I asked for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA...
To rename file name use the following syntax:

```
Name "BULK_CALL.ZIP" As "BULK_CALL2.ZIP"
```

To repeat procedure after 30 mins of time use instruction:

```
Application.OnTime
```

where you have to add two parameters.

Comment: I need something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310233/rename-single-file-from-list-in-directory

Comment: @user2151337: Did you actually try to apply [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310233/rename-single-file-from-list-in-directory/15310925#15310925 "Rename single file from list in Directory"), which you seemed to have accepted as the solution, although never [formally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?"), to this here problem?

Comment: I did apply that answer, it worked but it only applied it to the txt files not Zip. Apologies if I have duplicated.